# How to mock Include method of DbSet?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have the following method in my repository

```
public IQueryable<T> QueryWithInclude(String include)
        {
            return _dbSet.Include(include);
        }
```

How can I mock such a method I am using Moq. I can't seem to find out the correct way.

For e.g. I could do the following for

```
public IQueryable<T> Query()
            {
                return _dbSet;
            }

mockrepository.Setup(_ => _.Query()).Returns(foo.AsQueryable());
```

Also, if the mocking of such a method/s eventually turns out be difficult then is it wise to consider alternative implementations/ workarounds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your abstractions return `IQueryable` (like `DbSet`) then you can create your own `Include` extension to `IQueryable`.  Your code will automaticalyl invoke your new Include extension method.  When used on an abstraction that returns a `DbQuery`, it'll invoke the correct Invoke, else if it's a `IQueryable` instance it'll do nothing.  Adding this new extension method means that your current code *should* compile without any changes.

like such:

```
    /// see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx
    ///     
    /// The method has been modified from version that appears in the referenced article to support DbContext in EF 4.1 ->
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static class ModelExtensions {
        public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>
                (this IQueryable<T> sequence, string path) where T : class {
            var dbQuery = sequence as DbQuery<T>;
            if (dbQuery != null) {
                return dbQuery.Include(path);
            }
            return sequence;
        }
    }
```

So if your unit test uses a fake `IQueryable` list, the Include will do nothing.

I must add though that there are strong opinions on why it is bad and worthless to mock out EntityFramework.   If you haven't see them it may be worth it checking them out.

Comment: If I use your method , then my unit tests will need to have a reference to EF. I have separate Integration tests for testing the EF stuff. Thoughts ?

Comment: In your current design, how are you avoiding having to reference the EF assembly when testing your repository layer?

Comment: The reference to EF is there when I test the Repository, but not when I test the Service Layer. For the service layer shoudn't I mock my repository ? Or did I figure it out wrong ?

Comment: You could always post your code to CodeReview if you want someone to give an opinion.

Comment: I will post it to Code Review, Infact I did ask for some feedback when I started this out. When I reach a more functional stage I will ask for an official review there.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell you what you should or should not do... what i have shown you is a how to move the Include ext method onto IQuerable<T> interface so that during testing you can use a fake IQueryable<T> repository and in the actual code a DbQuery<T>.